# How to use one recycelerview for some different categories?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

for making an android application like the picture below(in the main page we have some categories and when we click on each of them there is a list of 40 items that each item can be clicked and read more about it)  i have 2 questions :
1) Is it better to use a recycelerview for the main page that has 6 or 8 icons or Is it better to use image buttons?

2)as we see we have different categories in this app so we have to make new recycelerview,adapter and ... for each of them or just use one for all of them?
[main page of the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZLr6.png)

Comment: use recyclerview , so you can dynamic change button positions and add new items from server side

Comment: @DivyeshPatel then is not bad to use a recyclerview inside another? i mean the app doesn't crash because of many recyclerviews?

Comment: on click of category new activity opens with recyclerview, so it is not bad but good practise

Comment: @DivyeshPatel each category has a specific activity right?

Comment: no, there is 1 activity for all item. You have to pass id of clicked category to next activity, and in that activity call api based on ID

Comment: @DivyeshPatel thanks :)  i will ask other questions when i get into it while coding

Answer (score 0):

For question number 2:
If you have a several list with same item, yes you can use one adapter and one `item.xml`
and although you can use `Intent.putExtra();` to handle this.